# Render web-part insinde control

Tags: web-part, user-controls

Is it possible to render a web-part inside of a control?

I have a webpart with a certain functionality which I want to re-use on a different page-layout directly.
 The first idea would be to extract the functionality into a control and then make the web-part display this control (loads of articles on the internet on how to do this...)

But: Is it possible to do it the other way around? I.E. have a control which embeds a web-part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web part is just a control, so anything you can do with a control you can do with a web part.

If you need the chrome(Title, border, etc) for a ASP.NET Web part then you need to add that yourself.

Comment: You're right. Simply adding the web-parts to the child-controls is fine. I had a different error leading to "empty rendering". Thanks.